# copying a node and saving it as a new xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml

im a newbie and this is my very first question on stackoverflow so bear with me please.

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
 <superitem>
  <item id="10" name="Ten"
        description="This is number ten">
    <attribute name="weight" value="1" />
    <attribute name="capacity" value="80" />
  </item>
  <item id="20" name="Twenty"
        description="This is might be number twenty">
    <attribute name="weight" value="1" />
    <attribute name="opaque" value="11" />
    <uncertain>
      <uncertainity name="might" level="Eighty Twenty."/>
    </uncertain>
  </item>
 </superitem>
</items>
```

And in the code I am trying to copy the node with id = 20

```
newItem.SelectSingleNode("/items/superitem/item[@id='20']")
```

And to save that only node to another xml file. So I'm trying to get an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
 <superitem>
  <item id="20" name="Twenty"
        description="This is might be number twenty">
    <attribute name="weight" value="1" />
    <attribute name="opaque" value="11" />
    <uncertain>
      <uncertainity name="might" level="Eighty Twenty."/>
    </uncertain>
  </item>
 </superitem>
</items>
```

I did a try by importing the node to an xml file after the last child of that xml and I could do that. What if I need a new xml file to be created with only that node? Output xml to be exactly like I have mentioned above??

Comment: Show us some code. How far have you gotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq to Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fname);

foreach (var item in xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/items/superitem/item[@id!='20']"))
    item.Remove();

xDoc.Save(fname);
```

Comment: But this will remove the mentioned node rather than choosing, won't it?

Answer (score 3):

Much easier with XElement (XLinq).

```
XElement oldDoc = XElement.Load(filename1);

//XElement items = oldDoc.XPathSelectElements("/items/superitem/item[@id='20']");
//XElement newDoc = new XElelement("items", new XElement("superitem", items));

// Because of using an XElement as toplevel (and not XDocumet), 
// the XPath has to start lower. And a Singular result is more to the point.
var item = doc.XPathSelectElement("//superitem/item[@id='20']");
XElement newDoc = new XElelement("items", new XElement("superitem", item));

newDoc.Save(fileName2);
```

Comment: Missed creating the variable newDoc.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
  <superitem />
</items>

this is the new xml. what if i need the data of the node with id 20??

Comment: You are right, my XPath is weak, and I tend to avoid XDocument. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

A badly looking but working solution for C#/.NET 2.0, if anyone needs it:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filename); // path to the .xml file
XmlNode selectedNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/items/superitem/item[@id='20']");

XmlDocument newXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration declaration = newXmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
newXmlDoc.AppendChild(declaration);

XmlNode itemsNode = newXmlDoc.CreateElement("items");
newXmlDoc.AppendChild(itemsNode);
XmlNode superitemNode = newXmlDoc.CreateElement("superitem");
itemsNode.AppendChild(superitemNode);

XmlNode itemNode = newXmlDoc.ImportNode(selectedNode, true);
superitemNode.AppendChild(itemNode);

newXmlDoc.Save(outputFileName); // name of the new .xml file
```

Using other answers is recommended if you aren't in need of a prehistoric code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to remove all the elements except the one you want to keep, then save to a new file:

```
    var xml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\input.xml");
    xml.Element("items")
       .Element("superitem")
       .Elements()
       .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value != "20")
       .Remove();
    xml.Save(@"c:\temp\output.xml");
```

Note that this does not perform any defensive checks against missing nodes, etc. It assumes it will always get what you've shown in your example- usually not a safe assumption for production code.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to xml is amazing.

here's some sample code that takes your super item and stores it in a new file.

```
 //Load the current xml
        var Document = new XDocument();
        Document = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"MyXmlFile.xml");


        //Get the Superitem based on id attribute (you'll want to do some checks to make sure that the xml has the relevent <superitem> node
        XElement superitem = Document.Root.Element("superitem").Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => (int?)x.Attribute("id") == 10);

        //check a superitem with the id was found
        if (superitem != null)
        {
            //Create New Document:
            var newDocument = new XDocument();
            newDocument.Declaration =
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

            //Create Root node (items)
            XElement root = new XElement("items");
            newDocument.Add(root);

            //Add the super item to the root.
            root.Add(new XElement("superitem", superitem));


            //Save
            newDocument.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"SuperItem.xml");
        }
```

Comment: In the time it takes me to write this, there's 50 new answers :) go fingers go!